# How to resotre the database with the build in tables in processmaker Version 3

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, processmaker

1. I have backup the workflow as .tar file using command line
2. And restore the workflow with the different name as a finance in command prompt windows 8
   I just follow this url : http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/Backing_up_and_Restoring_ProcessMaker
3. But only the empty database have been created "wf_finanace", which doesn't have a any build in tables like APPLICATION?

[please clik here to view an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0FMi.png)
please help me!!

Comment: What are the logs showing? What is the command line showing back?